# EOFError: EOF when reading a line in a calculator script

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

I'm trying to program a simple Python calculator but always when I run the code the Atom editor has a problem with reading this line:

```
while True:
     user_input = input(":")
```

Under this line of code I entered the methods for Python and told it what it should do:

```
if userinput == "quit":
        break
elif userinput == "add":
     num1 = float(input("Enter a number"))
     num2 = float(input("Enter another number"))
     result = str(num1 + num2)
     print("The answer is:" + result)
```

So now when I run this code the Atom editor says that it has a problem with reading this code and it won't ask me for an input as it should.
I think I didn't miss out any code.

Comment: the `if` and `elif` should be on the same indentation level

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to format it right: in Atom they are on the same level, but thank you anyways!

Comment: still this is most likely either mixed tabs and spaces or a missing parenthesis somewhere in your code

Comment: Ok, thank you I’m gonna look over it so!

Comment: I sorted it out, it was just Atom that didn’t work I tried to run the code in CMD and it worked totally fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely either mixed tabs and spaces or a missing parenthesis somewhere in your code. also the code has a few mistakes including indentation errors:

```
while True:
     user_input = input(":")
     if user_input == "quit":
          break
     elif user_input == "add":
          num1 = float(input("Enter a number"))
          num2 = float(input("Enter another number"))
          result = str(num1 + num2)
          print("The answer is:", result)
```

Comment: Maybe I just need to add a plug in for Atom in order to make it work, could that also be?

Comment: nope. no plugins required. Just make sure you're using tabs OR spaces consistently

Comment: I sorted it out, it was just Aton that didn’t work, I tried to run in CMD and it worked totally fine!